# Unable to de-sereailize WSresponse asJson() from HTTP server in Play with WSClient

Tags: java, playframework, jackson, playframework-2.4, ws-client

I get a WSResponse(form Play framework) response from an HTTP service as

> {"authToken":"d4b4bf6d5ff3f35366a75b498c8dbb58"}

which I am trying to read as JSON and print on console using

```
 System.out.println(response.asJson());
```

I get the response printed on console correctly, however, the code breaks in the function asJson() with the following trace:

> play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution
>   exception[[RuntimeException:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map
>   due to end-of-input  at [Source:
>   org.jboss.netty.buffer.ChannelBufferInputStream@23408f7c; line: 1,
>   column: 1]]]  at
>   play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:265)
>   ~[play_2.10-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]  at
>   play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:191)
>   ~[play_2.10-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]  at
>   play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:179)
>   [play_2.10-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]   at
>   play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:212)
>   [play_2.10-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]   at
>   play.api.http.GlobalSettingsHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:94)
>   [play_2.10-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]   at
>   play.filters.cors.AbstractCORSPolicy$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(AbstractCORSPolicy.scala:151)
>   [filters-helpers_2.10-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]    at
>   play.filters.cors.AbstractCORSPolicy$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(AbstractCORSPolicy.scala:150)
>   [filters-helpers_2.10-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]    at
>   scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:344)
>   [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]     at
>   scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:343)
>   [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]     at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
>   [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]     at
>   play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:70)
>   [play-iteratees_2.10-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]     at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40)
>   [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]     at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248)
>   [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]     at
>   scala.concurrent.Promise$class.tryFailure(Promise.scala:112)
>   [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]     at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryFailure(Promise.scala:153)
>   [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]     at
>   play.api.mvc.Filter$$anon$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(Filters.scala:67)
>   [play_2.10-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]   at
>   play.api.mvc.Filter$$anon$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(Filters.scala:61)
>   [play_2.10-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]   at
>   scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
>   [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]     at
>   play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$recoverM$1.applyOrElse(Iteratee.scala:629)
>   [play-iteratees_2.10-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]     at
>   play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$recoverM$1.applyOrElse(Iteratee.scala:629)
>   [play-iteratees_2.10-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]     at
>   scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
>   [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]     at
>   scala.util.Failure$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Try.scala:185)
>   [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]     at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
>   [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]     at
>   scala.util.Failure.recover(Try.scala:185)
>   [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]     at
>   scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Future.scala:324)
>   [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]     at
>   scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Future.scala:324)
>   [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]     at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
>   [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]     at
>   akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
>   [akka-actor_2.10-2.3.11.jar:na]   at
>   akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
>   [akka-actor_2.10-2.3.11.jar:na]   at
>   akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
>   [akka-actor_2.10-2.3.11.jar:na]   at
>   akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
>   [akka-actor_2.10-2.3.11.jar:na]   at
>   scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
>   [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]     at
>   akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:90)
>   [akka-actor_2.10-2.3.11.jar:na]   at
>   akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40)
>   [akka-actor_2.10-2.3.11.jar:na]   at
>   akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
>   [akka-actor_2.10-2.3.11.jar:na]   at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
>   [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
>   [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
>   [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
>   [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map
>   due to end-of-input  at [Source:
>   org.jboss.netty.buffer.ChannelBufferInputStream@23408f7c; line: 1,
>   column: 1]    at play.libs.Json.parse(Json.java:149)
>   ~[play-json_2.10-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]     at
>   play.libs.ws.ning.NingWSResponse.asJson(NingWSResponse.java:149)
>   ~[play-java-ws_2.10-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]  at
>   service.GlaasService.lambda$getAuthToken$0(GlaasService.java:28)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   service.GlaasService$$Lambda$74/930311498.apply(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   play.core.j.FPromiseHelper$$anonfun$map$1.apply(FPromiseHelper.scala:103)
>   ~[play_2.10-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]  at
>   scala.util.Success$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Try.scala:206)
>   ~[scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]    at
>   scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161) [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]    at
>   scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:206) ~[scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]
>     at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235)
>   ~[scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]    at
>   scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235)
>   ~[scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]    at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
>   [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]     at
>   play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext$$anon$2.run(HttpExecutionContext.scala:40)
>   ~[play_2.10-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]  ... 6 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map
>   due to end-of-input  at [Source:
>   org.jboss.netty.buffer.ChannelBufferInputStream@23408f7c; line: 1,
>   column: 1]    at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148)
>   ~[jackson-databind-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:3609)
>   ~[jackson-databind-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3549)
>   ~[jackson-databind-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:2078)
>   ~[jackson-databind-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]   at
>   play.libs.Json.parse(Json.java:147) ~[play-json_2.10-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
>     ... 17 common frames omitted

The cause of error looks like inappropriate end of input for json, however I verified the JSON response if working fine otherwise and the console statement is also printing it correctly, however its breaking just after printing it. If I try to process the response as JSON without printing, it still breaks with the same exception.

Adding the method code as below:

```
public static Promise<Result> getAuthToken(String serviceProfileId, String username, String password, WSClient ws){
                return ws.url("http://SERVER_URL/auth")
                .setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .post("serviceID="+serviceProfileId+"&username="+username+"&password="+password)
        .map( response -> {
            if(response == null)
                return play.mvc.Results.noContent();
            System.out.println(response.asJson());
            JsonNode json = response.asJson();
            if(json == null) {
                return play.mvc.Results.ok("Expecting Json data");
            } else {
                String token = json.findPath("authToken").textValue();
                if(token == null) {
                  return play.mvc.Results.ok("Missing parameter [auth Token]");
                } else {
                  return play.mvc.Results.ok("Hello " + token);
                }
            }

        });     }
```

Any inputs on how to resolve this are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Weird. Could you please share the whole method?

Comment: @marcospereira Updated. Please see if this helps clarify some issue.

Comment: Can you be sure your JSON string is valid? Have you tried printing with `System.out.println` it before using `response.asJson()`?

Comment: Yes @Kris I validated the printed json string and it's valid as mentioned in the question. The asJson() method is able to print the string on console but still breaks before exiting the asJson() method call.